# Story or book with character named "Bird" and homebuilt security robots

Tags: story-identification, books, robots

This was probably from the 70s or early 80s. It was post-apocalyptic, and featured home built (mostly small) robots that served to protect the character and his living space. The only character name I remember is "Bird".

Comment: Do you remember the general plot?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)